# Apply indicator from indicator

Tags: mql4

I am creating a custom indicator, when the user dropped the custom indicator into their chart, I want the Bollinger Band be shown on the chart too. Is there a way to achieve that within the custom indicator?

Answer (score 0):

only if you create three extra buffers and fill them in with Bands values. EA can show all employed indicators after backtesting is done, but in real time - no. As far as i know